# Adding navigation to QGIS Shapefile?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I'm looking to create an APP with Navigation Offline.

The problem is my point of interest is not offered by OpenStreetMap (OSM).

I would like to know if can i add navigation to a shapefile (mine) or should i add the new area to OSM?

Comment: "The problem is my point of interest is not offered by OpenStreetMap (OSM)" you can create an account and add your points of interest then your will see your own data in OSM > https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/new?cookie_test=true

Comment: The problem is the area have some staircase and some small street that not digitalized by OSM, and with the sat image resolution, It's too hard to detect theme ... that's why i thought for creation my db.

Comment: You can use your smartphone to record a GPX track. Then use this track for adding the steps to OSM. Aerial imagery can be helpful but isn't always needed.